# RecyclerView, DiffUtil and weird animation

Tags: android, animation, rx-java2, android-recyclerview

I have a chat app working with websockets.
Via websocket I receive message, which I save into db, messages table, and update `last message id` in conversation table. Now, both saves will notify cursor. So I call `updateDate` twice. They will run sequentially, in correct order and on correct threads. Yet, I guess, the animations are overlapping and making weird effect visible in [youtube video attached](https://youtu.be/on8EabRQgew) (visible from message "i"). Can anybody pinpoint my problem or give me solution?

I am using rxjava for threading and dequeue for stacking updates, while always getting only last update from dequeue. Inspiration from vlc [here](https://geoffreymetais.github.io/code/diffutil-threading/)

RecyclerView is stacking from end and if user is scrolled to bottom, then animation scroll to bottom is run when new message comes.

**Fragment**

```
adapter = ChatMessageAdapter()
recycler.apply {
    adapter = this@ChatDetailFragment.adapter
    layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false).apply { stackFromEnd = true }
}
```

**ChatMessageAdapter**

```
private val pendingUpdates: ArrayDeque<Single<Pair<MutableList<ChatItemHolder>, DiffUtil.DiffResult>>> = ArrayDeque()

@MainThread
fun updateData(msgs: MutableList<ChatMessage>, onDone: () -> Unit) {
    pendingUpdates.add(
        internalUpdate(msgs)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnSuccess {
                items.clear()
                items.addAll(it.first)
                it.second.dispatchUpdatesTo(this@ChatMessageAdapter)
                onDone()
            }
    )
    if (pendingUpdates.size == 1) pendingUpdates.peek().subscribe(Consumer {processQueue()})
}

private fun internalUpdate(msgs: MutableList<ChatMessage>) = Single.create<Pair<MutableList<ChatItemHolder>, DiffUtil.DiffResult>> {
    val newItems = temp(msgs) // transforming function from ChatMessage[] to ChatItemHolder[]
    val result = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(DiffUtilCallback(newItems, items), true)
    it.onSuccess(Pair(newItems, result))
}

@MainThread
private fun processQueue() {
    pendingUpdates.remove()
    if (!pendingUpdates.isEmpty()) {
        if (pendingUpdates.size > 1) {
            val last = pendingUpdates.peekLast()
            pendingUpdates.clear()
            pendingUpdates.add(last)
        }
        pendingUpdates.peek().subscribe(Consumer { processQueue() })
    }
}
```

Thank you!